# SQL COUNT DISTINCT values tied to record via JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I have 2 tables:

stock

```
StockID  |   ItemName   
1        |   hat           
2        |   hammer       
3        |   banana         
4        |   elephant    
5        |   book
```

and Basket

```
BasketID   |   StockID   | Quantity
1          |   3         | 5
2          |   2         | 20
3          |   1         | 7
4          |   2         | 60
5          |   5         | 23
6          |   1         | 17
7          |   3         | 3
8          |   4         | 6
9          |   3         | 1
10         |   2         | 1
11         |   2         | 13
```

I'm trying to make an SQL query which out puts the StockID, ItemName, Total Quantity Sold, and the Number of Orders that Item had.

I have this:

```
SELECT stock.StockID, stock.ItemName, SUM( basket.Quantity ) AS QuantitySold
FROM stock
JOIN basket ON stock.StockID = basket.StockID
GROUP BY stock.Itemname
ORDER BY stock.StockID
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Which works fine, but when I try adding:

```
COUNT (DISTINCT basket.BasketID)
```

I just get a message saying I have a Syntax Error.

I am fairly new to all this, so sorry if my logic is wrong, but shouldn't that just count the distinct values tied to stockID, as it does pretty much that with the SUM of quantity sold, where it locates all the basket.Quantity values tied to the stockID in the basket table.

All help much appreciated -Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the full answer to your question, but I don't think that in MySQL you can have a space between the function name and the leading parenthesis like you do with `COUNT`.

Comment: Ahahaha, removed the space and it works, always the simply things. Thanks :)

Comment: From the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions.html: "By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and the parenthesis following it." EDIT: with any other DB app it is okay.

Comment: Whoops, you're totally right. Funny thing, it is legal to use `if ( 3 = 3 , 1, 2 )` or even `MOD ( 29, 9 )`